# markov chain problem conditioned on future

Tags: probability, markov-chains

We know that by Markov property that $P ( X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1} , . . . , X_0 = x_0 ) = P ( X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1})$ but can we say that $P ( X_0 = x_0 | X_1 = x_1 , . . . , X_n = x_n ) = P ( X_0 = x_0 | X_1 = x_1)$, any hint on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
P(X_0=x_0 \mid X_1 = x_1,  \ldots, X_n = x_n)
&= \frac{P(X_0=x_0, X_1=x\ldots, X_n=x_n)}{P(X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_n = x_n)}
\\
&= \frac{P(X_0=x_0)\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i=x_i \mid X_{i-1} = x_{i-1})}{P(X_1=x_1)\prod_{i=2}^n P(X_i=x_i \mid X_{i-1} = x_{i-1})}.
\end{align}
The last step uses the Markov property. Cancelling terms will lead you to $P(X_0 = x_0 \mid X_1=x_1)$.